# CakePHP - how to simply reset cached database models

Tags: php, cakephp

I have several apps based on CakePHP and this basically applies to all of them. When my debug mode is set to 0 (live mode), every time I update the database structure, like new tables and fields, then as soon as my app uses those, I always get the default "An Internal Error Has Occurred" message. It is solved if I set debug to 1 and then use those new fields. Is there a better way to do this? I don't want to enable debugging and doing a test write every time I have to update my database. Also /tmp/cache subfolders are empty, so I don't know where it is stored.

Comment: You can simply clear files in "/app/tmp/cache" folders.

Comment: Like I said before - those folders are empty.

Answer (score 3):

You need to clear all cache configs

```
bin/cake cache clear_all
```

[Source](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/console-and-shells/cache.html)

Comment: to specifically clear just the model cache you can use:

`bin/cake cache clear _cake_model_`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function I wrote to do exactly that.

```
function clear_cache() {
    $cachePaths = array('js', 'css', 'menus', 'views', 'persistent','models');
    foreach($cachePaths as $config) {
        clearCache(null, $config);
    }
}
```

It uses the [clearCache](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/function-clearCache.html) function in Cake.

Answer (score 0):

For CakePHP 2.x, place this line of code anywhere in your application to clear the model cache:

`Cache::clear(false, '_cake_model_');`

This is decoupled from the low-level cache engine (File, Memcache, Redis, etc), so it should work as-is.

[CakePHP 2.x Docs: Caching](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-libraries/caching.html#Cache::clear)

Answer (score 0):

For cake 2.x, you can delete the cache directory like this:

```
 rm -rf app/tmp/cache/
```